# UILabel doesn't always show up in its superview

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uikit, uilabel

I'm trying to create a stack view with nested stack views of views to create a grid. Every cell in a grid should have a label. The problem I have is that label is showing only in the very first view as in [this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QWcz3.png):

Code of my main stack view is straightforward:

```
for _ in 1...5 {
    let view = WeekView()    
    addArrangedSubview(view)
}
```

And this is the code of a nested stack view.

```
// Function called in init(frame:)
func configureView() {

    spacing = 8

    for _ in 1...7 {
        let view = UIView()
        let label = UILabel()
        view.addSubview(label)
        addArrangedSubview(view)

        label.text = "hi"
        label.textAlignment = .center

        view.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40).isActive = true
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        label.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.heightAnchor).isActive = true
        label.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor).isActive = true
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    }
}
```

Any suggestions will be much appriciated.

Comment: You are not setting the position for the label, only its width and height.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, but I thought that if you move a view, all its subviews also move with it, isn't it true? But i tried to call `label.frame.origin = view.frame.origin` but it didn't help.

Comment: You cannot set the position using `frame` because your autoresizing mask is not used. You have to add constraints for X and Y position for every label. Otherwise the position will be random.

Comment: Thanks for clarification, now it works like a charm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not setting the position for the label. You could add the horizontal and vertical constraints, but you can also simply do:

```
label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = true
label.frame = view.bounds
label.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
```

instead of

```
label.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.heightAnchor).isActive = true
label.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor).isActive = true
label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be that you haven't set

```
label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
```

Please try to set that directly after you create the UI element:

```
let view = UIView()
view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
let label = UILabel()
label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
view.addSubview(label)
...
view.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40).isActive = true
view.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40).isActive = true
```

Yet, in your case I would highly recommend using a `UICollectionView`. You get a lot of things for free if you use it (including smooth horizontal scrolling).
The image looks like you are building some kind of calendar app. If you use a `UICollectionView` you also get a very flexible API for spacing and overall layout.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, I added `view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints`. Unfortunately it didn't help. Actually I was looking towards `UICollectionView` and I think I'm going to rewrite this code using it, before doing that though I really want to know why this label is behaving this way.